# Broken cross symbol for closing in notification message

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

After revoting on question opening or successful flag, cross symbol in the notification message is broken.

Revote for opening:

> [image]

Vote for opening:

> [image]

Comment: Also reported on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379617/unicode-fun-1832672-this-comment-cant-be-voted-on-seem-to-have-an-interesting). Thanks for the report! We're looking into it.

Comment: @Catija that looks like an encoding issue. Could have something to do with the suggested edit link shown as plaintext. IIRC these popular are loaded via AJAX. Maybe a missing header then?

Comment: On a dupe on MSO Shog said something about their [editor's encoding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379621/odd-looking-close-button-on-error-message?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment666504_379621)? @MEEisJohannGambolputty... I don't know what that means...

Comment: @Catija ah, I think the x symbol was entered in to a file that was (recently) edited in a program/text editor version that doesn’t understand Unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue seems to have been fixed (checked on Meta.SE, Meta.SO and one other site):

[image: Picture showing that the issue is fixed]

I am quite sure that the fix was related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323243/364003) answer by Nick Craver:

> **Update:** Meta has been reverted to master. We'll be at the drawing board figuring out how to fix this if anyone needs us.

Comment: Thing is, that bug happened in more sites, not only MSE, hence not sure it's same root cause. (bad .NET core build)

Comment: @ShadowWizard fix confirmed by me on MSO. I will look on other sites **EDIT** Also on totally unrelated site (Quantum Computing)

Comment: @ShadowWizard fixed on SOru too.