# Broken bounty post notices

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, post-notices

The post notices for bounties look broken on all 4 currently featured MSE questions (to me):

[image]

I can only see this on MSE, I put up a bounty to test stuff on IPS and it is looking good there:

[image]

Comment: related/similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323136/edit-approved-links-are-showing-as-plain-text

Comment: I can't repro on Chrome or Edge both on Win10...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2kr9.png I'm in a team on SO in case it is related to that.

Comment: The trick is to avoid questions with bounties on them

Comment: Reproduced in Edge.

Comment: @rene I'm in a team too and I was able to repro.

Comment: Repro on Meta, Windows 10, Firefox 64.0.2. No repro on SFF and Unix & Linux

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog are you also in the Custom list / new new new new nav test group?

Comment: @rene No, I am not.

Comment: Okay, I am so that might the difference between your result and mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** Meta has been reverted to master. We'll be at the drawing board figuring out how to fix this if anyone needs us.

---

Thanks for the report - we'll remedy this in a bit. For context: we're testing, specifically on meta (and only for half the users - 1/2 servers), a huge code change on our path to .NET Core. It looks like `@helper` feeds into our localization markdown renderer aren't being detected as already-encoded due to the massive type changes we're having to make since `IHtmlString`, `HtmlString` (System.Web), and `MvcHtmlString` all aren't in the new world.

There are likely a few other instances of this across the site happening for the same reason. We're going to leave this build up for a bit, get more feedback, and revert back to `master` while we fix the things found today.

Comment: Is [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323213/broken-cross-symbol-for-closing-in-notification-message) also related?